# string to variable name

Tags: c#

I have class(Customer) which holds more than 200 string variables as property. I'm using method with parameter of key and value. I trying to supply key and value from xml file.  For this, value has to be substituted by Customer class's property(string variables).

ie

```
Customer
{
  public string Name{return _name};

  public string Address{return _address};
}


CallInput
{
  StringTempelate tempelate = new StringTempelate();
  foreach(item in items)
  tempelate .SetAttribure(item.key, item.Value -->   //Say this value is Name, so it has to substitute Customer.Name
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you should consider redesign your class, 200 properties is kinda crazy :p
But for you method reflection is the way to go.
You could use a Dictionary<string, string> as an example.

Comment: are you looking for <customer> <name>John</name> <address>internets street</address></customer>

Comment: @ John Nolan, just similar to that

Comment: btw, the correct spelling is Template, not tempelate, and attribure should be attribute. I also don't use much C#, but the `"template .setAttribure"` as opposed to `"template.setAttribute"` is at least against conventions, and may be a syntax error.

Comment: @Macha for the spelling tempelate compiler won't give any exception and english is not my mother tongue. Space between the tempelate and setAttribute is mistake.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use reflection to set the properties 'by name'.

```
using System.Reflection;
...
myCustomer.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(myCustomer, item.Value, null);
```

You can also read the properties with GetValue, or get a list of all property names using GetType().GetProperties(), which returns an array of PropertyInfo (the Name property contains the properties name)

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can use [`Type.GetProperty(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) to get a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx), then call [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx).

For example:

```
// There may already be a field for this somewhere in the framework...
private static readonly object[] EmptyArray = new object[0];

...

PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(item.key);
if (prop == null)
{
    // Eek! Throw an exception or whatever...
    // You might also want to check the property type
    // and that it's readable
}
string value = (string) prop.GetValue(customer, EmptyArray);
template.SetTemplateAttribute(item.key, value);
```

Note that if you do this a lot you may want to convert the properties into `Func<Customer, string>` delegate instances - that will be *much* faster, but more complicated. See my blog post about [creating delegates via reflection](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Reflection is an option, but 200 properties is... a lot. As it happens, I'm working on something like this at the moment, but the classes are created by code-gen. To fit "by name" usage, I've added an indexer (during the code generation phase):

```
public object this[string propertyName] {
    get {
        switch(propertyName) {
            /* these are dynamic based on the the feed */
            case "Name": return Name;
            case "DateOfBirth": return DateOfBirth;
            ... etc ...
            /* fixed default */
            default: throw new ArgumentException("propertyName");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the convenience of "by name", but good performance.

Answer (score 4):

Use reflection and a dictionary object as your items collection.

```
Dictionary<string,string> customerProps = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Customer myCustomer = new Customer(); //Or however you're getting a customer object

foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Customer).GetProperties())
{
    customerProps.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(customer, null));
}
```