# Use of string as an existing variable in c#

Tags: c#, variables

```
string one = "find";
combobox1.text = "one";
```

I want to use "one" i.e string value of (`combobox1.text`) as an existing variable `string one`.
Is this possible?

All you still didn't getting my question. I want to use value of **combobox1.text** that is **one** and **one** that is variable string and it value is **find**. so i want to use variable **one**'s value indirectly.

Comment: one = combobox1.Text? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name and several others like it. Bundle your string variables into a class and either use Reflection technique or GetProperty. (Not putting this as an answer since I think this question should be closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it for local variables like this. For member fields you can use [*reflection*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); for locals, the simplest approach is to use `Dictionary`, for example, like this:

```
IDictionary<string,string> vars = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    {"one", "find"}
,   {"two", "cancel"}
};

combobox1.text = vars["one"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use:

```
combobox1.text = one;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: no you didn't understand my question. I want to use combobox1.text's value that is one and one's value that is find.

Comment: you want to add to your combobox the word "find" located in the variable one, right?