# Accessing a public class member dynamically

Tags: c#

```
public class Names
{
    private string _name1 = "";
    private string _name2 = "";
    private string _name3 = "";

    public string Name1
    {
      get { return _name1; }
      set { _name1 = value; }
    }

    public string Name2
    {
      get { return _name2; }
      set { _name2 = value; }
    }

    public string Name3
    {
      get { return _name3; }
      set { _name3 = value; }
    }
}

collection Names = new Names();
```

I have a long string of text (longString).  If the text at position 10 is 2, then I need to set values for two of the Names: Name1 and Name2.  My variables are in a class that I have already instantialized.  So I need to dynamically set the values of a dynamic number of variables.  How do I call the variables and set the values dynamically?  Basically something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= collection.Count(); i++)
{
    col.Name + i = longString.Substring(11, 4);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [string to variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name)

Comment: Why does `Names` have numbered properties?  Why not just use a  `List<string>` of names?

Comment: As an aside, your code would also be a lot shorter if you used automatically implemented properties.

Comment: Kirk and Jon - do you have examples of these?

Comment: @divided Google them and read the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Names
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= collection.Count(); i++)
{
    var col = collection.ElementAt(i);
    col.GetType().GetProperty("Name + i").SetValue(col, longString.Substring(11, 4), null);
}
```

Name1, Name2 and Name3 are auto-implemented properties. We're using reflection to get the properties by name and to set its values.

Answer (score 1):

Faster than using reflection:

```
public class Names
{
    private string[] _names = {"", "", ""};
    public string[] Names { get {return _names; } } // ReadOnlyCollection?

    public string Name1
    {
       get { return _names[0]; }
       set { _names[0] = value; }
    }
}
```