# Get dictionary name by string in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

I have a class which contains 4 dictionaries.

```
public class FishInformation
    {
        public int FishId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,int> DicGroup { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> DicEvent { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> DicAudience { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> DicType { get; set; }
    }
```

I want get the dictionary name by a string and add items to it. So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name) suggests using `System.Reflection` to do so. this is the code I tried:

```
 FishInformation fishinfo =new Global.FishInformation
            {
                FishId = fishId,
                DicAudience =  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
                DicEvent =  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
                DicGroup =  new Dictionary<string, int>(),
                DicType =  new Dictionary<string, int>()
            };
string relatedDictionary  //It's the variable which contains the string to merge with "Dic" to get the property

fishinfo.GetType().GetProperty("Dic" + relatedDictionary).SetValue(fishinfo, myKey, myValue);
```

I just can figure out how to make it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated? I suggest this solution/design:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dicName = "Group";
        var fishInfo = new FishInformation();
        string myKey = "myKey";
        int myValue = 1;
        fishInfo.Dictionaries[dicName][myKey] = myValue;
    }
}

public class FishInformation
{
    public FishInformation()
    {
        Dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>()
        {
            { "Group", new Dictionary<string, int>() },
            { "Event", new Dictionary<string, int>() },
            { "Audience", new Dictionary<string, int>() },
            { "Type", new Dictionary<string, int>() }
        };
    }

    public int FishId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> Dictionaries { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GroupDic
    {
        get { return Dictionaries["Group"]; }
    }

    // ... other dictionary getters ...
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put `var` before `Dictionaries = new ...` ? Cz it throws error without it

Comment: Anyways, Like the idea! Thanks

Comment: No, you must not put var before Dictionaries because it's a property and you assign a new value to it. If you put var there it would make it a local variable and wouldn't work anymore. If you get an error then you need to define the property. I guess you might  overseen it?

Answer (score 3):

Your code sets the value for the entire dictionary, rather than adding a string to an existing dictionary.

You need to call `GetValue`, not `SetValue`, cast it to `IDictionary<string,int>`, and add the value to it:

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string,int>)fishinfo
    .GetType()
    .GetProperty("Dic" + relatedDictionary)
    .GetValue(fishinfo);
dict[myKey] = myValue;
```

This is not the most efficient way of doing this - you could use an `enum` instead:

```
enum InfoDict {Group, Event, Audience, Type};
public class FishInformation {
    public int FishId { get; set; }
    private IDictionary<string,int>[] infos = new IDictionary<string,int>[] {
        new Dictionary<string,int>()
    ,   new Dictionary<string,int>()
    ,   new Dictionary<string,int>()
    ,   new Dictionary<string,int>()
    };
    public IDictionary<string,int> GetDictionary(InfoDict index) {
        return infos[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws `No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments` error at `.GetValue(fishinfo);`

Comment: @AlexJolig This method should be there in .NET 4.5 ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx)). If you are on .NET prior to 4.5, try ``.GetValue(fishInfo, new object[0])` instead.

Comment: VoteUp for your solution. Thanks. But I'm gonna go with @t3chb0t answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll probably need to call GetValue() first to retrieve the dictionary, add the item to the dictionary and lastly call SetValue() (scratch that); because you're trying to modify the dictionaries contents and not the dictionary as a whole.

Edit: SetValue() isn't necessary as you're dealing with a reference type.