# How is the number one pick textbox from text box

Tags: c#

I want the value of a variable number Number textbox I get it.
example

```
textbox1 textbox4
textbox2 textbox5
textbox3 textbox6
int e = int .parse(textbox1.text);
string w = textbox+(e);
```

Comment: exciuse me i cant write english good

Comment: Can you please explain it more clear. Do you want to get the value from a textbox into an integer variable and then from that integer variable into another string variable + another textbox text?

Comment: I think you want reflection - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name

Comment: i have multi textbox , i want to choose number of textbox from another text, how should i do ?

Comment: example:    textbox(random.next(50))    or   textbox(textbox1.toint())

Comment: thanks dimitry and artem dear, you undrestand how i want.        but i cant use this.       i will change backcolor textboxt where number in textbox1.

Comment: i write       ("textbox"+int.parse(textbox1.text)).bachcolor = color.blue;       please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public void SetBackColor(string controlName)
{
   var controls = this.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
   var control = controls.FirstOrDefault();
   if (control != null)
   {
      var textBox = (TextBox)control;
      textBox.BackColor = Color.Bisque;  // some stuff with finded textbox.
   }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
SetBackColor("TextBox" + int.Parse(textbox1.Text));
```

Comment: thanks dimitry and artem dear, you undrestand how i want. but i cant use this. i will change backcolor textboxt where number in textbox1.("textbox"+int.parse(textbox1.text)).bachcolor = color.blue

Comment: So. What is a problem? You got the textBox and can work with it as usual. I updated in answer with backcolor changing.

Comment: i will if textbox1=15,     textbox15.backcolor=color.black.

Comment: or textbox1=8, textbox8.backcolor=color.black.

Comment: If you want to use it easier - you can create void and use it. I updated answer with example how you can do it.

Comment: i have another question , ask you here or in new topic ?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection solution:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
FieldInfo fi = this
  .GetType()
  .GetField("textbox" + textbox1.Text, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

if (fi != null) {
  TextBox result = fi.GetValue(this) as TextBox;
  ... 
}
```

Comment: thanks dimitry and artem dear, you undrestand how i want. but i cant use this. i will change backcolor textboxt where number in textbox1.                  ("textbox"+int.parse(textbox1.text)).bachcolor = color.blue