# JsonSerializer.Serialize throws exception

Tags: c#, json

I have a list and I want to write it to a file but `JsonSerializer.Serialize(mylist)`throws an error
here is the code:

```
private void CheckIfFileExistsOrCreateOne()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            LoginInfo secretary = new LoginInfo("secretary", "secretary", new Secretary_Form());
            LoginInfo admin = new LoginInfo("admin", "admin", new Administrator_Form());
            mylist.Add(secretary);
            mylist.Add(admin);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonSerializer.Serialize(mylist));
        }
    }
```

and the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you show LoginInfo class declaration?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the line `File.WriteAllText...` and inspect the `myList` object. You should be able to see what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can't pass a form to a list and write it to a file because it's too large
so I changed my strategy and I used [string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name) to approach what I wanted.