# Is there a way to dynamically change which variable is being set based on the value of another variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I want to be able to set some variables in C# by reading a text config file. I created a function "ReadConfigFile()" that reads the file and returns an array of strings.

Example output of ReadConfigFile():

```
[Variable1=1234, Variable2=true, Variable3=MyCatIsGray]
```

Currently the way I'm setting my variables using the array is by using a bunch of if statements like the code bellow shows. But obviously this becomes quite tedious if I'm using proper names for my variables, and I if I want to have a lot more variables.

```
public int Variable1 = 0;
public bool Variable2 = false;
public string Variable3 = "";

public void Configure()
{
    string[] config = ReadConfigFile();

    foreach (string line in config)
    {
        string[] variableAndValueArray = line.Split("=");

        if (variableAndValueArray[0] == "Variable1") { Variable1 = VariableAndValueArray[1]; }
        if (variableAndValueArray[0] == "Variable2") { Variable2 = VariableAndValueArray[1]; }
        if (variableAndValueArray[0] == "Variable3") { Variable3 = VariableAndValueArray[1]; }
    }
}
```

So I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. I was hoping something like this would be possible:

```
public int Variable1 = 0;
public bool Variable2 = false;
public string Variable3 = "";

public void Configure()
{
    string[] config = ReadConfigFile();

    foreach (string line in config)
    {
        string[] variableAndValueArray = line.Split("=");
        
        variableAndValueArray[0] = variableAndValueArray[1]
        //I want the line above to change which variable it is setting based 
        //on the value of variableAndValueArray[0]
    }
}
```

I've tried to look up information about doing something like this but since I don't know the proper terminology for things, it was hard finding anything.

Comment: Maybe you could use a Dictionnary, where the key is your variable name and the value is its value. So instead of calling the variable `Variable1`, you can call `variables["Variable1"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string to variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WhyV - You'll have to use reflection. Check out the following code

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SO temp = new SO();
        temp.Configure();
    }
}

class SO
{
    public int Variable1 = 0;
    public bool Variable2 = false;
    public string Variable3 = "";

    public void Configure()
    {
        string[] config = new string[] { "Variable1 = 1234", "Variable2 = true", "Variable3 = MyCatIsGray" };

        foreach (string line in config)
        {
            var variableNamePart = line.Split('=')[0];
            var variableValuePart = line.Split('=')[1];

            variableNamePart = variableNamePart.Trim();
            variableValuePart = variableValuePart.Trim();

            FieldInfo fld = typeof(SO).GetField(variableNamePart);

            if (fld.FieldType == typeof(System.Int32))
            {
                fld.SetValue(this, int.Parse(variableValuePart));
            }
            if (fld.FieldType == typeof(System.Boolean))
            {
                fld.SetValue(this, Boolean.Parse(variableValuePart));
            }
            if (fld.FieldType == typeof(System.String))
            {
                fld.SetValue(this, variableValuePart);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Variable1 is " + Variable1);
        Console.WriteLine("Variable2 is " + Variable2);
        Console.WriteLine("Variable3 is " + Variable3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Dictionary*, let it be `Dictionary<string, object>`, e.g.

```
// Convert (Parse) text from config file into proper value
private static object TextToObject(string text) {
  if (int.TryParse(text, out int intValue))
    return intValue;
  if (text.Trim() == "true" || text.Trim() == "false")
    return text.Trim() == "true";
  
  return text;
}

...

// Read config an turn it into a dictionary
// Simplest: no duplicate keys check
Dictionary<string, object> VariableAndValue = config
  .Select(line => line.Split('='))
  .Where(pair => pair.Length == 2)
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0].Trim(), pair => TextToObject(pair[1]));
```

Then you can query `VariableAndValue` as follow

```
// If VariableAndValue has Variable1 of type int then...
if (VariableAndValue.TryGetValue("Variable1", out var o) && o is int Variable1) {
  //TODO: Put relevant code here
}
```